# How to copy java file to a workspace programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to create a java file from scratch using AST but it is painstakingly taking me longer to finish. What I have in mind is create the java file, then create the project and package and then copy that file to that package. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org), in order to create Java classes from templates. In my case, i had to create from (velocity) templates some classes (and maven pom) using Eclipse Wizards. But if you want to modify these classes, then the best choice would be AST/JDT.

[http://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/JDT_Tutorial:_Creating_Eclipse_Java_Projects_Programmatically](http://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/JDT_Tutorial%3a_Creating_Eclipse_Java_Projects_Programmatically)

shows how to create a java project using JDT and configure your classpaths subsequently.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried the JDT Tutorial. Simple enough for a quick hack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JBoss forge](http://forge.jboss.org/) to generate java classes problematically. it has api to write scaffolding plugins. it uses Apache Velocity templates to do that.

Also [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) can be another choice, if you are a Spring guy ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`IFile#setContents(InputStream ...)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IFile.html#setContents%28java.io.InputStream,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor%29) would seem like a good candidate.

You can also use the [`ImportOperation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12485531/60462) to import files from anywhere (incl. the filesystem outside of the workspace) into a project.